Postgresql table partitions insert based on local time zone not utc
I am trying to create a table with partitions based on utc hour but when I insert record, it ends up into partition based on my local time zone, ie. EST.
Here is some code:
Column: audio_file_start_unix_millis is an epoch bigint down to milliseconds
create table voice.voicetext
(
    audio_file_start_unix_millis    bigint not null,
    facility                        varchar(4) not null,
    dalr_channel                    int not null,
    audio_file_end_unix_millis      bigint not null,
    processed_timestamp_unix_millis bigint not null,
    audio_file                      varchar(150) not null,
    segment_uuid                    varchar(50) not null,
    speaker_role                    varchar(20) not null,
    audio_file_uuid                 varchar(50) not null,
    diarization_confidence          numeric(9,8) not null,
    segment_start_unix_millis       bigint not null,
    segment_end_unix_millis         bigint not null,
    transcription_uuid              varchar(50) not null,
    transcription_confidence        numeric(19,18) not null,
    transcription_text              text not null,
    control_position                varchar(10),
    speaker_gender                  int,
    adddate                         timestamp default current_timestamp,
    addwho                          varchar(50) default current_user,
    editedate                       timestamp default current_timestamp,
    editwho                         varchar(50) default current_user,
    constraint un_voicetext unique (audio_file_start_unix_millis,facility,dalr_channel,control_position)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (audio_file_start_unix_millis);

create index idx_voicetext_start_timestamp on voice.voicetext( timezone('Etc/UTC',to_timestamp(audio_file_start_unix_millis::decimal/1000)));

SELECT partman.create_parent( p_parent_table => 'voice.voicetext',
                p_control => 'audio_file_start_unix_millis',
                p_type => 'native',
                p_epoch => 'milliseconds',
                p_interval=> 'hourly',
                p_premake => (24*28),
                p_start_partition =>  date_trunc('day', (current_timestamp at time zone 'utc') - interval '45 day')::varchar
);

This will create hourly partitions going 45 days back and 28 days forward. This works fine.
I am expecting when a record is inserted that the partition it lands in would be related to it's utc conversion not est.
Example:
insert into voice.voicetext(audio_file_start_unix_millis
,facility
,dalr_channel
,audio_file_end_unix_millis
,processed_timestamp_unix_millis
,audio_file
,segment_uuid
,speaker_role
,audio_file_uuid
,diarization_confidence
,segment_start_unix_millis
,segment_end_unix_millis
,transcription_uuid
,transcription_confidence
,transcription_text
,control_position
,speaker_gender)
values( 1727740793391
,'XXX'
, 21090
, 1727740810784
, 1728541141116
, 's3://bucket/file.txt'
, 'xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
, 'controller'
, 'filename'
, 0.992303
, 1727740798431
, 1727740801451
, 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx'
, 0.7172371354862196
, 'does not matter'
, 'XX'
, null);
select audio_file_start_unix_millis from voice.voicetext_p2024_09_30_1900;
audio_file_start_unix_millis|
----------------------------+
               1727740793391|

I would have thought it would need up in voice.voicetext_p2024_09_30_2300
Since this is what that column translates to:
GMT: Monday, September 30, 2024 11:59:53.391 PM
Your time zone: Monday, September 30, 2024 7:59:53.391 PM GMT-04:00 DST
Any help would be appreciated on how to get the value into the, what I am calling, correct partition?

Are you aware that all timestamps are stored as UTC?

Use timestamptz. Regular timestamp takes the current time and throws away the UTC offset, while timestamptz uses it to align the value with UTC. I don't think the bigint based timestamp is a great idea and I wouldn't expect any sort of timezone awareness from it. pgpartman recommends that you set timezone to 'utc'; in sessions that run partition maintenance commands.

@FrankHeikens Yes I am aware. Did you read my example and issue? pg_partman is storing record based on the time zone I am in, NOT UTC. When dropping partitions I will have to compensate for that.

@Zegarek The column driving the partitioning is a bigint epoch based number. The only place I use timestamp is in the index created on top of the partitioning column and I add time zone utc.  Also this data has millions of records per hour and do NOT want to transform this column to timestampz. This setup works as is. The issue is pg_partman puts the records into the hourly partition based on EST not UTC. Guess at this point, seting the session timezone maybe my only recourse.
